# How to connect to an Active Directory

Tags: linux-mint, active-directory

My office has a telemarketing group that is running Windows XP on ancient hardware. I want to move them off of XP as quickly as possible, for obvious reasons.  These telemarketers rely solely on web based applications, so I thought why not use Linux?  Its free and relatively virus proof.  I installed Linux Mint 17 LTS and installed it on a machine and had one of the telemarketers test it out.  It worked fine and she said it was faster than XP.

I want to connect Mint to Active Directory, there seems to be a number of options, but I am confused.  Most of my Google searches point to a product called Likewise Open, but it appears the product is discontinued.  Some things point to a product called PowerBroker, but it appears to be a paid product.

I also ran across a product called Centrify, but it doesn't support Mint 17.

What is the easiest way to connect Mint 17 to AD to use AD logons?

Comment: Do you have an AD that you want to maintain or can you consider migrating the rest of the infrastructure? BTW, Samba + Kerberos is almost the only you need. [Take a dip on the topic](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Active_Directory_Integration)

Comment: You can use `realmd` to join an AD. If you are migrating away from Microsoft, I'd recommend a more comprehensive solution like freeIPA. I don't know if the server is already ported to Debian derivatives, but the client surely is.

Comment: @Braiam AD and Windows will still be the core of the IT infrastructure.  This company is not IT focused, so there isnt much budgeted for hardware or OS upgrades.  Thats why I thought Linux would be a good replacement for these ailing XP machines.  Actually, there are other machines I would consider upgrading to Linux, the users are almost entirely using cloud based apps.  Unfortunately, some of these web apps are IE only.

Comment: I also want to add that I chose Mint, as it seems the most user friendly Linux distro.  Ubuntu seems like to much of a departure from Windows standards.  But Im open to other distros if they are better suited in some way.

Comment: WRT the IE only apps, you could use this: https://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads  -- I dunno how it will fly on the hardware, but perhaps worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

It should just work fine with our latest Centrify Suite 2014 agent, which can be downloaded from:

http://www.centrify.com/express/free-active-directory-tools-for-linux-mac.asp#agents

(You can select Centrify Agent for Linux Mint 32-bit or Linux Mint 64-bit)

Mint 17 will be officially supported by our up-coming Suite 2014.1, which will be released in around late August.

To install Centrify DirectControl using a native installation program:

1  Log on as or switch to the root user.

2  Since the software package is a compressed file, please unzip and extract the contents.

3  Run the appropriate command for installing the package, for example, on Linux Mint computer:

.dpkg -i centrifydc-5.1.3-.deb

4  Disable licensed features by running the adlicense --express command:

adlicense --express

Note You must run the adlicense command to set the agent to run in Express mode.

5 Join the domain by running the adjoin --workstation command, which connects you to Auto Zone:

adjoin --workstation

e.g.

adjoin --workstation domain.com

Note If you do not specify the --workstation option, the join will fail because adjoin will attempt to connect you to a specific zone rather than Auto Zone.

6   Run the following command to start up Centrify agent:

/usr/share/centrifydc/bin/centrifydc start

In the following website there are several how-to video clips and documentations for you to better understand our products:

http://www.centrify.com/express/free-active-directory-tools-for-linux-mac.asp

If you have any questions with our products, please feel free to go to our Centrify Express Community forum and post your questions or search for the answers from others’ posts.

If you are interested in our paid version, you may sign up and request a trial. You will then be followed by Centrify staffs and help you out during the evaluation:

Hope this helps.

Best Regards,

Henry

Centrify Technical Support

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether my answer comes too late, but since you said, you are also open to other distros, I can truly recommend the Linux distro Univention Corporate Server (UCS). I do work for Univention, the open source manufacturer of UCS, but I can honestly say that UCS really provides all you seem to need:

- Easy-to-use centralized, web-based management via the Univention Management Console of UCS 
  and
- Full AD services including an easy migration of an existing AD to UCS via the integrated assistant „Active Directory Takeover“, which let's you migrate complete MS Active Directory domains including user (rights), groups (policies) and computers. No further action is necessary and the users don't recognize any changes.

The Active Directory Takeover wizard is available via the Univention App Center, which is integrated in UCS.

You can find details about UCS on its product site of the Univention homepage at:
https://www.univention.com/products/ucs/ and further details about all UCS functions at:
https://www.univention.com/products/ucs/functions/

For testing UCS and the Active Directory Takeover wizard for free, download an ISO- or VM-image in form of a free-for-personal use license, go then to the App Center within the system's management console and install the wizard from there. The App Center offers also numerous proven, popular open source solutions which all integrate in UCS and can be managed centrally.If you want, you can also try some of these during your test.

I hope, my answer was of help to you and maybe other readers.

Best regards,
Maren